# What is the most efficient way to achieve such layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to achieve the following layout in one of my android applications:

[image: Layout to build]

Edit:

I also need the selection of one of the elements to be displayed in a similar way as that:

[image]

So each of the 3 elements have to take 1/3 of the Horizontal space to make the selection drawable big enough.

/Edit

I can't find most efficient way to make it.

I've first tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/forums_navbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/forums_navbar_height"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/forums_navbar_TextView_debut"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/forums_nav_debut"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/forum_nav_blue"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/nav_fast_backward">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/forums_navbar_TextView_precedent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/forums_nav_precedent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/forum_nav_blue"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/nav_backward">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/forums_navbar_TextView_suivant"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/forums_nav_suivant"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/forum_nav_blue"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dip"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/nav_fast_forward">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is not exactly what expected:

[image: Bad one]

I've changed the layout to have it work:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/forums_navbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/forums_topics_navbar_height"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/forums_navbar_TextView_debut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/forums_nav_debut"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/forum_nav_blue"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawablePadding="4dip"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/nav_fast_backward">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/forums_navbar_TextView_precedent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/forums_nav_precedent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/forum_nav_blue"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawablePadding="4dip"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/nav_backward">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/forums_navbar_TextView_suivant"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/forums_nav_suivant"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/forum_nav_blue"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawablePadding="4dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/nav_fast_forward">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result:

[image: good]

It works, but it's just not efficient at all. Is there a better way?

Comment: just change gravity of textviews in your first layout to: (in order)
`android:gravity="left"`, `android:gravity="center"`, `android:gravity="right"`

Comment: In fact the position of the text in the TextViews is in the right place. The drawable are not.

Comment: why ? this is what i get with your 1st layout and "gravity fix" http://esilo.pl/selvin/layout1.png (android:gravity="left", android:gravity="left", android:gravity="right")

Comment: works fine for the left and right one, but for the center element, the drawable keep sticked to the left of the TextView. I want it to be in the center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to have `RelativeLayout` at top.

1. use `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for Left side view
2. use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for Center view
3. use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for Right view

Output:

[image]

You can have above output by using below solution:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">   // For view at Left side
    </TextView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">  // For view at center
    </TextView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">  // for view at Right side
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I need to have each element in 1/3 of the screen and the "Left" and "Right" TextView need to be centred in their 1/3 of space. In your solution there are stick to the screen border.

Comment: @ol_v_er my dear you should have mentioned your requirement correctly. check all answers are coming for the same solution :(

Comment: Sorry you were right, the designer sticked to "Début" and "Suivant" to the borders of the screen. My first comment is not correct. I'm going to take a coffee...

Comment: @ol_v_er Still you can try solution-2 for your above comment.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani how your second solution is different(i mean in visual) from his first layout from the question?

Comment: Solution 2 is the same as my first Layout. It would work if there were not android:drawableLeft and so on. There are automatically sticked to the boarder of the TextView.

Comment: @Selvin just the difference of layout_width="0dp" in my case to have equal width for all views. Actually i just gave quick answer as i got his comment :)

Comment: Sorry all for my quickness. I just have removed solution-2

Comment: @Paresh Mayani fill_parent(he has it in his layout) will do the same

Comment: I just edit the Question to add the problem of the selection drawable. With such user interaction feedback, the solution @Paresh Mayani with 3 warp/wrap TextView does not work. Sorry to add important details like that after.

Comment: use your first solution and play with  android:gravity="left"

Comment: works fine for the left and right one, but for the center element, the drawable keep sticked to the left of the TextView

Comment: what do you want for center element exactly?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is textview with a drawable sticked to the text in the center of the view

Comment: Because it's the best response for my initial question, I validate it

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a relativelayout as top and then put the three groups in each their linearlayout.
Then for each group (linearlayout) you can set android:layout_alignParent to center, left and right.

Comment: My dear you are right, but why need to take LinearLayout as a sublayout for three groups?

Comment: I though he had more than a textview in them :) but he don't so I guess the linearlayouts isn't needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. As **Warpzit** said, use a `RelativeLayout`. That should easily do the trick: just align the middle one in the middle (`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`) and the other ones to the left and right (`android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, same for right).
2. With a `LinearLayout`, you could have the three `TextView`s have a `android:layout_width="0px"` (yes, zero pixels) and a `layout_weight="1"`. This will make the `LinearLayout` give the `TextView`s equal widths. Now you just have to align the text to the left, center and right respectively in each of the `TextView`s, which you can do using `android:gravity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" 
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" 
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_weight="0.34">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```